# Random forest regression for outlier detection

Tags: regression, random-forest, anomaly-detection

I am using Random Forest (**RF**) on a set of financial data. Normally when using RF, you split the data into a training and a test dataset.

However, I just want to find outliers.

When using RF to detect outliers, what is the best way to do this? Just run a normal model, and then use that model to predict on the same dataset as the model was built upon? Does it make sense to have a train and test dataset?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Soren.

Answer (score 4):

There are some well developed algorithms that use trees to detect outliers. The key observation in these algorithms is that outliers correspond to short path lengths in fully developed trees. In other words, if you train a tree to leave only one sample at each leaf, you will notice that the path length (i.e. number of splits) of outliers is relatively small. So, the path length is a measure of normality.
In a random forest setting, the feature used to split data is chosen randomly from the set of all possible features. Thus, if you use 10 trees, your measure of normality of a certain point will be a function of its average path length among all trees. This is essentially the idea of [isolation forest algorithm](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html#sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest). Although it uses Extra tree regressions as a bagging model, the intuition is the same. I'm not sure if there are other, conceptually different, algorithms for outlier detection using trees, but this approach is pretty sound.

Answer (score 0):

Saleh has a good answer.

If you require several to many values to be in a bag, the CART should replace them with their mean.  In the bagging that **random forests** do, because it is a mean of subsampled means and several of the trees will not have the sample in them, the mean is a robust estimate and is less moved by outliers.  You can look at distance between predicted value and actual value, and outliers will tend to have higher distance.  You can "turn up this dial" by making your bootstrapped columns and rows be a smaller percentage of the whole, but don't overdo it.

Depending on your RF tool, you can trim your trees before adding them to the ensemble.  If you trim/prune the trees before adding them to the ensemble, they can be more robust and thus give a bit of a stronger signal for outliers.  Note: this is for a random forest not an isolation forest.

The isolation forest that Saleh mentioned is looking to have one or very few leaves per tip.  It then looks at the number of splits to get to each leaf, and those that take much fewer are likely farther from the rest in a general sense. Pruning wouldn't necessarily do much good for it.

Comment: how can it be that pruning helps isolation forests? what kind of pruning?